# how to loop infinite times by repeating same elements with single list in python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying this and getting Memory error.

```
A = [a,b,c,d]
for i,j in zip(cycle(A), itertools.count()):
    print (i+str(j))
```

how can i print this output:

```
[a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2, a3, b3, c3, d3 .. infinite times]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on Python 2.7, and `zip` tries to create a list from an **inexhaustible** iterator; your memory simply blows up. Use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could proceed:  ( I added a break from the loop after 10000, you can remove it to get to infinity and beyond)

```
import itertools

A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for idx, letter in enumerate (itertools.cycle(A)):
    print(letter + str(idx), end=' ')

    if idx == 10000:
        break
```